# Setting elements to opaque animation and disabling clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my jQuery is:

```
$('.wpcf7:hidden').parent().children().children().toggle(function(){
        $(this).css({opacity: '0.25'}, 200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({opacity: '1'}, 200);
    }); // get all other hidden elements and set to opaque
```

However, I don't want the toggle slide in and out functionality. I just want the elements to decrease their opacity and disable all the links within that element.

Thanks

Comment: What elements should be made more opaque? Where do the links reside? Could you show the HTML, please? How about a JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
$('.wpcf7:hidden').parent().children().children().toggle(function(){
        $(this).css({opacity: '0.25'}, 200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({opacity: '1'}, 200);
    }).click(false);
```

OR

```
$('.wpcf7:hidden').parent().children().children().toggle(function(){
            $(this).css({opacity: '0.25'}, 200);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css({opacity: '1'}, 200);
        });
$('.wpcf7:hidden').parent().children().children().click(false);
```